# Update Image without losing the old path in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

i need help.

I want to update image in Edit page, but just when it is necessary.

the problem is whenever i do an edit i have to upload the image again.

i want to keep the old image if i do not want to update it.
hope you all understand me.

this is the view :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonalImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label  " })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <img  src="~/Content/Uploads/Adherentes/Personalimages/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonalImage)" width="80" height="80"  id="uploadperso" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; cursor: pointer"/>
                                <input onchange="showPhoto(this);" type="file" accept="Image/*" id="PersonalImage" name="PersonalImage" class="form-control" />

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonalImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and this the update controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(HttpPostedFileBase PersonalImage, adherent adherent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           
                string _ImageName = Path.GetFileName(PersonalImage.FileName);
                string _Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Adherentes/Personalimages"), _ImageName);
                PersonalImage.SaveAs(_Path);
                adherent.PersonalImage = _ImageName;
            
            

            _db.Entry(adherent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();

           

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(adherent);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your `showPhoto()` function

Comment: i dont use showphoto function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i found out the solution.

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var data =  _db.adherents.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Id == adherent.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            string PersonalImagePath = data.PersonalImage;

            data = null;
            if (PersonalImage != null && PersonalImage.ContentLength > 0 )
            {
                string _ImageName = Path.GetFileName(PersonalImage.FileName);
                string _Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Adherentes/Personalimages"), _ImageName);
                PersonalImage.SaveAs(_Path);
                adherent.PersonalImage = _ImageName;

            }
            else
            {
                adherent.PersonalImage = PersonalImagePath;
            }
                    
            
            
            _db.Entry(adherent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
```

Thank you for all who participated in this
Thank you @Ramp2010

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database and controller doesn't require an image. You can adjust your controller method to search for an image provided before writing.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       if(PersonalImage != null){

            string _ImageName = Path.GetFileName(PersonalImage.FileName);
            string _Path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Adherentes/Personalimages"), _ImageName);
            PersonalImage.SaveAs(_Path);
            adherent.PersonalImage = _ImageName;
        
        

        _db.Entry(adherent).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();

       

      }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Hello Ramp2010, thanks for yours answer, but when i tried this one, i got an error :
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

on that line :
`if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PersonalImage.FileName)){`

so i guess it might be something else.

Comment: Updated my answer, I mistook FileName as a string when it's actually HttpPostedFileBase object. So you can just check if the provided file is null and skip the database update.

Comment: i tried it before but still gives me the same error
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Comment: Last edit should fix it.

Comment: No not at all, i just cant see where is the problem, 
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**
why this ?

Comment: That error usually occurs when you are trying to work with an object that's null. So if you are trying to read or update the object's property "FileName" for example, but the object doesn't exist (Null) an error will be thrown. Place a break point at the If statement and hover over the "PersonalImage" object to see if it's null.

Comment: hi again, i did a breakpoint and yes the PersonalImage is null, 

**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

PersonalImage was null.**

the error message.

Comment: So you need to make adjustment to the if statement to prevent it from continuing. if(PersonalImage != null). I'm surprised this doesn't work.

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Comment: Try placing a break point here, (ModelState.IsValid), to confirm the ModelState is valid.

Comment: it is valid otherwise it won't go the next statement which is our condition

Comment: Try passing in a new image and break point "if(PersonalImage != null){" to see if it's passing the image?

Comment: Yes it's passing the image

Comment: Can you try changing the signature to this?
public ActionResult Edit(adherent adherent, HttpPostedFileBase PersonalImage = null)

Comment: Hello, no icant because it doesnt accept it

Comment: Do you have your code on a repo? I'm stumped without looking through the code myself.